# IBM i (AS400) file transfer issue. Pound symbol changes

Tags: ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator, attachmate-extra

So i have been trying to transfer files from my system to as400. When i transfer the file from my system, the pound symbol in the file changes to some garbage character. Can anyone suggest something??

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I know nothing about AS400 but there's some thing called "encoding": a set of rules that computers use to convert binary digits into actual letters. You have to find out which one your data set is using and which one the target system expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does sound like a CCSID mis-match.  How are you trying to transfer files?  If using IBM i Access Data Transfer, then there is a setting under File > Properties > Conversions called 'Convert CCSID 65535'.  If your system is set to CCSID 65535, then Data Transfer has to guess at the encoding of the characters.

You probably want to change either the system value QCCSID to match the actual language (US English is 37), or change the particular table (you might create a view with the proper CCSID...)

Comment: Although nearly all systems **should not** use QCCSID 65535 (especially if any network data transfers are done), the system value should not be changed before determining how it might impact normal operations. Most sites should see no problems, but it's definitely possible to run into one or more.